# How many threadgroups?

Tags: ios, metal

Within iOS Metal the documentation says that a [single threadgroup can only be associated with a single compute unit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/func-var-qual/func-var-qual.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH4-SW12). So I'm curious if choosing a number of threadgroups should be dependent on the number of available compute units? Is there a penalty for having more threadgroups than compute units? If it is important to match the number of compute units to threadgroups, how can one determine on a given device the number of available compute units?

Answer (score 1):

*Here's my current understanding of how this works. I mostly came up with this mental model based on the Metal documentation combined with [this awesome video from NVIDIA](https://youtu.be/nRSxp5ZKwhQ?t=1630).*

- You will need a minimum amount of threadgroups (NVIDIA's "*thread blocks*"), in your grid, to get your job done. Yes, it will take longer if you have more threadgroups than can execute concurrently, but that does not equate to a "penalty" for using more threadgroups. It just means that your problem requires a lot of processing.
- The number of threadgroups that a compute unit can handle concurrently varies based on memory needed and available. You can't assume how many of your threadgroups might be executing concurrently.

The only clear rule I have currently for designing kernel functions is that the threadgroups represent multiples of the **thread execution width** (NVIDIA's "*warp granularity*").

I don't yet have clear rules for using threadgroup vs. device memory, due to probabilistic compute unit utilization, other than to use threadgroups in a way that's easiest to think about and code, first.